# RecyclerView scroll up and toolbar disappears

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I have a fragment in which it has two simple layouts, a map and then a recycler view. Since the recycler view is at the bottom, its scrolling and seeing items will be difficult. 
So, is it possible, that as I scroll down items in recyclerview all items above it goes off and only recyclerview items are shown. Also, as I scroll up all items are again shown up.
Could someone assist me on how to do it.

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. [See this post about CoordinatorLayout and Behavior](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)